# What is mongodb_plugin used for?

Tags: database, data-storage, chainbase

I have some confuse with chain_plugin and mongo_plugin, why do we need them? And if I can modify chainbase which can write directly state to disk, Do I can discard mongoDB?

Comment: Regarding SSD instead of RAM: https://medium.com/@bytemaster/eosio-ram-market-bancor-algorithm-b8e8d4e20c73 & https://steemit.com/eos/@eosio/storage-costs-on-blockchains-using-eos-io-software Hard disk would be out of the question as it wouldn't be fast enough.  Another kind of storing state would be IPFS.

Comment: What is IPFS? Do you have any documents for this? &Nat

Comment: Yes.  Think of IPFS as torrenting.  steemit uses IPFS for large file storage.  As does dtube.  https://steemit.com/eos/@eosio/eos-io-storage-white-paper-now-available

Answer (score 1):

`chain_plugin` is actually the core part that manages the blockchain data structure in `nodeos`. Most of time it is enabled automatically.

`mongo_db_plugin` is an add-on plugin that aims to replace the previous `history_plugin` and `history_api_plugin`, and is for data access / analysis / reporting purpose only. It is more like a peripheral module attached to the nodeos core and it can not work without `chain_plugin`. If you do not need a mongodb database for query, you can definitely disable `mongo_db_plugin` and it will save huge amount of system resources.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. And I think  chainbase which be used to store longest chain but mongo_db cannot.

Comment: @Onotoko Yes, chainbase is where actual chain data is stored.

Comment: If I store all data of action traces, transactions and blocks everything on MongoDB, still will it consume chain state memory? I want to get rid of the exception ```Database has reached an unsafe level of usage, shutting down to avoid corrupting the database. Please increase the value set for "chain-state-db-size-mb"```

Comment: @Varsh Yes chain state still will consume the same amount of memory regardless of how you setup your MongoDB plugin. For the exception, refer to https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5107